# How to draw candlesticks with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, candlestick-chart

using flutter and the package [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) I would like to draw a candlesticks graph along with other lines ( e.g. macd ) and the volume at the bottom. Unfortunately I cannot understand how to draw a candle along with the rest of the graph. Would anyone willing to show me an example code on how to do it? A candle could even be represented with a vertical line along with a rectangle on top of it.

A couple of example graphs can be seen [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/macd.asp)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/k_chart 
To run demo code, you also need to set assets https://github.com/OpenFlutter/k_chart/blob/master/example/assets/depth.json

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:k_chart/flutter_k_chart.dart';
import 'package:k_chart/k_chart_widget.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<KLineEntity> datas;
  bool showLoading = true;
  MainState _mainState = MainState.MA;
  bool _volHidden = false;
  SecondaryState _secondaryState = SecondaryState.MACD;
  bool isLine = true;
  bool isChinese = true;
  List<DepthEntity> _bids, _asks;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData('1day');
    rootBundle.loadString('assets/depth.json').then((result) {
      final parseJson = json.decode(result);
      Map tick = parseJson['tick'];
      var bids = tick['bids']
          .map((item) => DepthEntity(item[0], item[1]))
          .toList()
          .cast<DepthEntity>();
      var asks = tick['asks']
          .map((item) => DepthEntity(item[0], item[1]))
          .toList()
          .cast<DepthEntity>();
      initDepth(bids, asks);
    });
  }

  void initDepth(List<DepthEntity> bids, List<DepthEntity> asks) {
    if (bids == null || asks == null || bids.isEmpty || asks.isEmpty) return;
    _bids = List();
    _asks = List();
    double amount = 0.0;
    bids?.sort((left, right) => left.price.compareTo(right.price));
    //累加买入委托量
    bids.reversed.forEach((item) {
      amount += item.vol;
      item.vol = amount;
      _bids.insert(0, item);
    });

    amount = 0.0;
    asks?.sort((left, right) => left.price.compareTo(right.price));
    //累加卖出委托量
    asks?.forEach((item) {
      amount += item.vol;
      item.vol = amount;
      _asks.add(item);
    });
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff17212F),
//      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 450,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: KChartWidget(
                datas,
                isLine: isLine,
                mainState: _mainState,
                volHidden: _volHidden,
                secondaryState: _secondaryState,
                fixedLength: 2,
                timeFormat: TimeFormat.YEAR_MONTH_DAY,
                isChinese: isChinese,
              ),
            ),
            if (showLoading)
              Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 450,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ]),
          buildButtons(),
          Container(
            height: 230,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: DepthChart(_bids, _asks),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildButtons() {
    return Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        button("分时", onPressed: () => isLine = true),
        button("k线", onPressed: () => isLine = false),
        button("MA", onPressed: () => _mainState = MainState.MA),
        button("BOLL", onPressed: () => _mainState = MainState.BOLL),
        button("隐藏", onPressed: () => _mainState = MainState.NONE),
        button("MACD", onPressed: () => _secondaryState = SecondaryState.MACD),
        button("KDJ", onPressed: () => _secondaryState = SecondaryState.KDJ),
        button("RSI", onPressed: () => _secondaryState = SecondaryState.RSI),
        button("WR", onPressed: () => _secondaryState = SecondaryState.WR),
        button("隐藏副视图", onPressed: () => _secondaryState = SecondaryState.NONE),
        button(_volHidden ? "显示成交量" : "隐藏成交量",
            onPressed: () => _volHidden = !_volHidden),
        button("切换中英文", onPressed: () => isChinese = !isChinese),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget button(String text, {VoidCallback onPressed}) {
    return FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (onPressed != null) {
            onPressed();
            setState(() {});
          }
        },
        child: Text("$text"),
        color: Colors.blue);
  }

  void getData(String period) {
    Future<String> future = getIPAddress('$period');
    future.then((result) {
      Map parseJson = json.decode(result);
      List list = parseJson['data'];
      datas = list
          .map((item) => KLineEntity.fromJson(item))
          .toList()
          .reversed
          .toList()
          .cast<KLineEntity>();
      DataUtil.calculate(datas);
      showLoading = false;
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((_) {
      showLoading = false;
      setState(() {});
      print('获取数据失败');
    });
  }

  //获取火币数据，需要翻墙
  Future<String> getIPAddress(String period) async {
    var url =
        'https://api.huobi.br.com/market/history/kline?period=${period ?? '1day'}&size=300&symbol=btcusdt';
    String result;
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      result = response.body;
    } else {
      print('Failed getting IP address');
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: cloned the repo and `flutter run` the example folder. this seems outdated vs. the current version of Flutter.

Answer (score 7):

I recently needed this so I made one from scratch.

**Usage:**

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
  child: InteractiveChart(candles: _data),
)
```

**Source:**

You can [check out my repo](https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter-interactive-chart) and modify it towards your needs.

Or you can [use the package directly from pub](https://pub.dev/packages/interactive_chart).

There are more screenshots / gif demos in the GitHub page as well.

[image: Candlestick chart demo]

It's easy to use, but it doesn't expose many settings (yet), so if you want to modify stuff you might have to clone the repo and modify the `CustomPaint` in the core.